# Getting Hibernate exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hql

Using spring boot 2.0. I have a class where there is a named query trying to get value from a constant class;

```
package com.abc.xyz.ddd.pkg;
@NamedQueries({       
        @NamedQuery(name = "Test.findbyAge", query = "select test from Test test" +
                " where test.name in (:nameList) and nvl(test.id, 0) <= com.abc.xyz.ddd.Constants.ID"))
})
public class Test{
    
    
}
```

constant class is as:

```
package com.abc.xyz.ddd;    
public class Constants {

    public final static int ID = 100;
    
}
```

error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:
Test.findbyAge failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'com.abc.xyz.ddd.Constants.ID'

Comment: You can not use java class constant explicitly in the JPQL/HQL query. You should pass it as query param

Comment: any example please that I can look at

Comment: What is `nvl()` here ?

Comment: nvl() is null check function. see here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=971983

Comment: You can do like `@NamedQuery(name = "Test.findbyAge", query = "select test from Test test where test.name in (:nameList) and COALESCE(test.id, 0) <= "+ com.abc.xyz.ddd.Constants.ID)` and make sure `Constants.ID` is string or convert it into string

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rewrite your query in this way:

```java
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
       name = "Test.findbyAge",
       query = "select test from Test test where test.name in (:nameList) and nvl(test.id, 0) <= :constantsID"
    )
})
public class Test {
}
```

and then just pass `com.abc.xyz.ddd.Constants.ID` in this way:

```java
entityManager
  .createNamedQuery("Test.findbyAge", Test.class)
  .setParameter("constantsID", com.abc.xyz.ddd.Constants.ID)
  ...
```